# Can i change side buttons on mouse on mac?

Tags: mac, mouse

Am I able to change the side buttons on my mouse on mac? It is a cyberpowerpc mouse. I've tried system preferences, but nothing there can change the mouse buttons. I've looked for other methods online, but the software to be able to change the button is for pc only.

Answer (score 0):

You need a 3rd party mouse driver to use 'extra' buttons on a 3rd party mouse or re-purpose regular buttons.

I use [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) though I've heard good reports of [USB Overdrive](http://usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html) too [both approx $20].